# Extract values at point locations from ArcGIS Server layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-server

I have a shapefile with several soil sampling locations (as points) I also have a ArcGIS Server layer (as .lyr) for the same region. I would like to extract the ArcGIS Server layer value at each point (as in the Extract values to points tool in ArcGIS). Is it possible to perform using ArcMap or similar?

Comment: Does Mapserver mean the ESRI MapServer or the open source MapServer?

Comment: I think it is ESRI MapServer: https://opendata.wvgis.wvu.edu/arcgis/rest/services/CarbonScapes/RaCA_SoilOrganicCarbonStocks/MapServer